# What is the best current Magic the Gathering AI?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, computer-ai

I am aware of MTG AIs in the following WOTC products and fan-made projects:

- Forge
- Duels of the Planeswalkers
- MTG Arena (Sparky)
- XMage
- Magarena

I am interested in a quantitative comparison between these AI's and any others that I may have missed. The Magarena wiki provides a helpful list of [Zermelo scores](https://github.com/magarena/magarena/wiki/AIComparison) comparing the different AI's in Magarena, but there is no comparison to AI's outside of Magarena.

Are there any other MTG AI haven't I heard of? How do these AI's compare?

Comment: This is a modified version of this question in an attempt to better conform to the rules of this site: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/52949/what-are-some-of-the-best-current-magic-the-gathering-ais

Comment: Someone deleted the linked question.  Can this question be reopened?